# Basic fit lognormal or gamma distribution

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I am extremely new in data distribution fitting.
I browsed some webpages and found some interesting R packages, such as `fitdistrplus`.
However, it seems too complex to a novice.
I have a example data that I create randomly:

```
dt <- data.table::fread("
       Days `2014Count` `2015Count` `2016Count`
       0           0           0           0
       1         757        1590         711
       2        1641        2430        2538
       3        8719       10378       13944
       4       13489       17745       23887
       5       38064       52103       61749
       6       14000       18413       24871
       7        8148       10534       14384
       8        9341       11609       15991
       9        5946        6805        9400
       9        5946        6805        9400
      10        6881        8475        9889
      11        4297        5091        6160
      12        4732        6065        6101
      13        3149        3990        4163
      14        2336        3169        3648
      15        1972        2547        3006
      16        1472        1762        2126
      17        1020        1380        1816
      18         890        1079        1004
      19         557         813         722")
```

If I want to check which distribution can fit my data, what is the first step?
I try to plot each of `Count`, and all three look like `lognormal` or `gamma` but seems to have large parameter.
I have no idea how to begin. Is there any reference to study for a rookie?
Thanks!

Comment: Asking for off-site references is considered off-topic. Asking "where to being" is too broad a question. Please try to edit your post to ask a specific question that can be answered below. If you tried code, include the code you ran and describe more precisely what the problem with it was.

Comment: The Poisson, binomial and negative binomial distributions are commonly used to represent count distributions. You should try to fit these first.

Comment: @F.Privé Oh. Thanks. But what is the first step? Any references that I can review and learn?

Comment: @PeterTW Not sure. I think some people just fit lots of distributions and use the one that fits the best. Not sure it's good practice though.